# whats diff between oauth2client and oauth2login? and where to use them individually

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I see `HttpSecurity.oauth2Client` and `HttpSecurity.oauth2Login` in Spring Security. As i knew, authorization only in oauth2client, both authorization and authentication in oauth2login. where to use each one of them?